# check in blade view if image is loaded or 404

Tags: image, laravel, view, controls, laravel-blade

Is there a way to check in a blade view if an image is really there or not?
I need to show results from a search box.
The results are many boxes with infos and a picture for each box.
The point is in my DB I store links to images that are on remote servers and also name of images that are stored locally.
So what I am doing is check if the file exists locally and if so use it and if not look on the remote server (if the picture data is not NULL it's either there or in a remote server).
I was trying to check if file exists using curl and it works but for big collections it takes too much time to finally spit the data to the view (every link has to be checked).
So what I want to do, if possible, is check directly in the blade view if the picture is not broken (404) and if so replace with an "image-not-found.png" I store locally. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle this with JavaScript using the `img` tag's [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/image#a-onerror) event. Typically I add a few more bells and whistles to the solution but this is it in a nutshell.

Plan JavaScript

```
function loadNextImage(id,uri){
  document.getElementById(id).src = uri;
}
```

Plain HTML

```
<img src="http://local/image.jpg" 
  onerror="loadNextImage('image1', 'http://remote/imae.jpg'));" 
  id='image1' />
```

VueJS and Webpack

```
<template>
  <img :src="local_url" @error="imgOnError()" ref="image"/>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    name: 'Thumbnail',
    props: {
      local_url: String,
      remote_url: String
    },
    methods: {
      imgOnError: function (e) {
        this.$refs.image.src = this.remote_url
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the func "file_get_contents" inside a try-catch block. I know i not the best way, but i could work for you.

Tray this (no the best way):

```
<?php
        try{
            $img = 'myproject.dev/image.jpg';
            $test_img = file_get_contents($img);
            echo "<img src='{$img}'>";
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "<img src='img/no-img.jpg'>";
        }
    ?>
```